# Adding Popover to TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopover, twui

I've been struggling with this for awhile and was hoping anyone could shed some light on why this isn't working.

I'm simply try to implement a Popover on a TableViewCell. Here is the code..

**TodoView.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(TUITableView *)tableView didClickRowAtIndexPath:(TUIFastIndexPath *)indexPath withEvent:(NSEvent *)event {

    // MyViewController is a TUIViewController with a nib called MyView with just a button in it
    MyViewController *t = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    TUIView *theView = [[TUIView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300)];

    TUIPopover *myPopover = [[TUIPopover alloc] initWithContentViewController:t];
    [myPopover showRelativeToRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300) ofView:theView preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}
```

For awhile, nothing would show up. I could tell something was happening though because the window itself would lose focus as if a Popover *was* there.

Sometimes I see a very small blip– like a small rectangle 2px by 2px. It's hard to see it, looks like dead pixel on the screen, but it appears sometimes when I run this code.

The TUIPopover is from the [Twitter UIKit Framework](https://github.com/twitter/twui).

*Some possibilities...*

1) The popover cannot be seen over the CGFillRect?

**TodoTableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect b = self.bounds;
    CGContextRef ctx = TUIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 247.0/255, 247.0/255, 247.0/255, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, b);
}
```

2) The popover doesn't fit inside the TableViewCell and cannot be seen

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple answer:

**I forgot to set the content size of the popover!**

So, for anyone else who is wondering why their popup isn't working, make sure you set the content size!

```
TUIPopover *p = [[TUIPopover alloc] initWithContentViewController:commentsViewController];
[p setAnimates:TRUE];
[p setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 350)];
[p setBehaviour:TUIPopoverViewControllerBehaviourTransient];
[p showRelativeToRect:b.bounds ofView:b preferredEdge:CGRectMinYEdge];
```